# Error in Array and Cases of Equation

Tags: amsmath

I am doing the following equation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
    x_{i+1}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        \left(4 a x_{i}\left(1-x_{i}\right)+2 b y_{i}\right) \bmod 1 & \text { for } y_{i}<0.5 \\
        \left(4 a x_{i}\left(1-x_{i}\right)+2 b\left(1-y_{i}\right)\right) \bmod 1 & \text { for } y_{i} \geq 0.5 \end{array}\\ 
     y_{i+1}=\left\begin{cases}\left(4 a y_{i}\left(1-y_{i}\right)+2 b x_{i}\right) \bmod 1 & \text { for } x_{i}<0.5 \\
        \left(4 a y_{i}\left(1-y_{i}\right)+2 b\left(1-x_{i}\right)\right) \bmod 1 & \text { for } x_{i} \geq 0.5\end{cases} \right.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

But unfortunately I am getting the following errors

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted). ^^I y_{i+1}=\left\begin{cases}
Missing delimiter (. inserted). ^^I y_{i+1}=\left\begin{cases}
```

Somebody please help me to correct these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you mix `array` and `cases`. But `\begin{cases}` doesn't want `\left` in front of it: it supplies the extending brace by itself.

You shouldn't use `\left` and `\right` inside the `cases` environment: they actually do nothing except adding unwanted spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  x_{i+1}&=
  \begin{cases}
    \bigl(4 a x_{i}(1-x_{i})+2 b y_{i}\bigr)    \bmod 1 & \text{for } y_{i}<0.5 \\
    \bigl(4 a x_{i}(1-x_{i})+2 b(1-y_{i})\bigr) \bmod 1 & \text{for } y_{i} \geq 0.5
  \end{cases}
\\[1ex]
  y_{i+1}&=
  \begin{cases}
    \bigl(4 a y_{i}(1-y_{i})+2 b x_{i}\bigr)    \bmod 1 & \text{for } x_{i}<0.5 \\
    \bigl(4 a y_{i}(1-y_{i})+2 b(1-x_{i})\bigr) \bmod 1 & \text{for } x_{i} \geq 0.5
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `aligned` you're sure that the inner braces are horizontally aligned.

I suggest omitting the outer left brace (just remove `\left\{` and `\right.`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `\right.` after the `\end{array}` that encloses the possible values for *x*<sub>*i*+1</sub>.

*but*, when you're writing the values for *y*<sub>*i*+1</sub>, you aren't using `cases` correctly. The whole point of `cases` is that you don't need to do the `\left\{`…`\right.` dance. It's taken care of for you. You will see that you would get a doubled { on the second line.

I'm not sure about *why* you would want the outer curly brace. That seems like really odd notation to me, but never mind. You'll find that you're better off writing your equation as:

```
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
    x_{i+1} = 
     \begin{cases}
       all the junk that goes here
     \end{cases}
     \\
    y_{i+1} = 
     \begin{cases}
       all the junk that goes here
     \end{cases}
\right.
```

The line breaks, incidentally are for more than just fitting things on screen, they also make it easier to see the structure of what you're creating.